# Representation is reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Suppose $V$ is a representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and suppose dim$V=3$ and $\wedge ^2V$ is reducible. Then $V$ is reducible.

I was trying to do it by contradiction. Suppose $V$ is irreducible, and as dim$\wedge^2V=3$, then either $\wedge^2V=V$, which is impossible as $V$ will be reducible, or $(\chi_V,\chi_{\wedge^2V})=0$. I do not know how to continue from here, any help would be great.Thank you.

Comment: I have been thinking about this, and although I'm not sure, it might be useful to use the definition of reducibility, namely that there exists a (1-dimensional) invariant subspace of $\wedge^2 V$.

Answer (score 2):

I want to take advantage of the fact that $\wedge^3V$ is 1-dimensional.

We have a non-degenerate bilinear mapping $B:V\times \wedge^2V\to \wedge^3V$ defined by
$$
B(v_1,v_2\wedge v_3)=v_1\wedge v_2\wedge v_3
$$
and extending linearly. Non-degeneracy follows from the facts that A) any non-zero vector of $V$ can be included in a basis $\{v_1=v,v_2,v_3\}$ and B) because $dim V=3<4$ any non-zero vector of $\wedge^2V$ is of the form $v_2\wedge v_3$ for some pair of
linearly independent vectors $v_2,v_3\in V$. Furthermore, by the definition of the action of $G$ on the exterior powers we get that
$$
B(gv,gv')=g B(v,v')
$$
for all $g\in G, v\in V, v'\in \wedge^2V$.

If $M\subset \wedge^2V$ were a non-trivial subrepresentation, then I claim that
$$
M^{\perp_B}:=\{v\in V\mid B(v,m)=0\ \text{for all $m\in M$}\}
$$
would be a non-trivial subrepresentation of $V$. Non-degeneracy of $B$ implies
that $\dim M^{\perp_B}=\dim \wedge^2V-\dim M=3-\dim M$. Also if $v\in M^{\perp_B}$ then
for all $g\in G$ and all $m\in M$ we have
$$
B(gv,m)=B(gv,gg^{-1}m)=gB(v,g^{-1}m)=g\cdot0=0.
$$
This implies that $gv\in M^{\perp_B}$ proving the claim.

Comment: Alternatively, if $\chi$ is the character of $\wedge^3V$ you can use $B$ to construct an isomorphism from $V\otimes k_{\chi^{-1}}$ to the dual of $\wedge^2V$ (unless I messed up soomething :-). The latter is then irreducible because the former is, and hence so is also $\wedge^2V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very hard proof.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't do too good a job here. The idea is simple, and it would be even simpler if the character of $\wedge^3 V$ were trivial. Basically what I'm saying is that $V$ and $\wedge^2 V$ are duals of each other modulo tensoring by the character of $\wedge^3 V$. Therefore if one is reducible so is the other. I'm sure Derek Holt, Geoff Robinson or Jack Schmidt (or some other resident experts) could make this more lucid :-(